# Mysql InnoDB optimisation

Tags: mysql, innodb

(asked on stackoverflow but was suggested to move here!)

I'm having some trouble understanding InnoDB usage - we have a drupal based DB (5:1 read:write) running on mysql (Server version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10-log (Ubuntu)). Our current Innodb data/index sizing is:

Current InnoDB index space = 196 M Current InnoDB data space = 475 M

Looking around on the web and reading books like 'High performance sql' suggest to have 10% increase on data size - i have set the buffer pool to be (data+index)+10% and noticed that the buffer pool was at 100%...even increasing about this to 896Mb still makes it 100% (even though the data + indexes are only ~671Mb?

I've attached the output of the innodb section of mysqlreport below. Pages free of 1 seems to be suggesting a major problem also as well. The innodb_flush_method is set at its default - I will investigate setting this to O_DIRECT but want to sort out this issue before.

```
__ InnoDB Buffer Pool __________________________________________________
Usage         895.98M of 896.00M  %Used: 100.00
Read hit      100.00%
Pages
  Free              1            %Total:   0.00
  Data         55.96k                     97.59 %Drty:   0.01
  Misc           1383                      2.41
  Latched           0                      0.00
Reads         405.96M    1.2k/s
  From file    15.60k     0.0/s            0.00
  Ahead Rnd       211     0.0/s
  Ahead Sql      1028     0.0/s
Writes         29.10M    87.3/s
Flushes       597.58k     1.8/s
Wait Free           0       0/s

__ InnoDB Lock _________________________________________________________
Waits              66     0.0/s
Current             0
Time acquiring
  Total          3890 ms
  Average          58 ms
  Max            3377 ms

__ InnoDB Data, Pages, Rows ____________________________________________
Data
  Reads        21.51k     0.1/s
  Writes      666.48k     2.0/s
  fsync       324.11k     1.0/s
  Pending
    Reads           0
    Writes          0
    fsync           0

Pages
  Created      84.16k     0.3/s
  Read         59.35k     0.2/s
  Written     597.58k     1.8/s

Rows
  Deleted      19.13k     0.1/s
  Inserted      6.13M    18.4/s
  Read        196.84M   590.6/s
  Updated     139.69k     0.4/s
```

Any help on this would be greatly apprectiated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your InnoDB Log Files (ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1) sized correctly ?

They should be 25% of the InnoDB Buffer Pool
In your case, that would be 224M

You can it them as follows:

1. Add this setting to /etc/my.cnf : innodb_log_file_size=224M
2. service mysql stop
3. rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile[01]
4. service mysql start (ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 are recreated)

You should keep the default for [innodb_flush_method](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/clarification-on-mysql-innodb-flush-method-variable/1575#1575) to insure ACID compliance. Otherwise, you could lose up to one second's worth of transactions.

CAVEAT: If your DB server is dedicated to only to the database, you should [reserve 75-80%](https://serverfault.com/questions/252918/innodb-memory-usage-mysql/252972#252972) or RAM for the innodb_buffer_pool.

**UPDATE**

You will definitely want to change your InnoDB layout !!!!

You need to raise innodb_open_files to 6000
You need to turn on innodb_file_per_table
[You need to restructure all InnoDB Data to reside in separate tablespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)

Comment: Hi Rolando, thanks for that. I actually set the buffer pool to a gig and the log files (accordingly) to 250Mb. After a restart, the buffer pool has already gone to 100% ... what i am not understanding is why it can get this large even though the data+indexes is < 700Mb?

Comment: What are your settings for innodb_data_file_path, innodb_open_files and innodb_file_per_table ?

Comment: mysql> show variables like "innodb%file%";
+---------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                  |
+---------------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_data_file_path     | ibdata1:10M:autoextend |
| innodb_file_io_threads    | 4                      |
| innodb_file_per_table     | OFF                    |
| innodb_log_file_size      | 262144000              |
| innodb_log_files_in_group | 2                      |
| innodb_open_files         | 300                    |
+---------------------------+------------------------+

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise that that would not format correctly! The system had already been configured like this prior to this optimisation process..

Comment: I will update my answer with more optimizations

Comment: Thanks for the update - i will test this and respond with my findings.